# How does codec logic work on android play store?

Tags: android, optimization, android-ndk

Some applications are publishing codec packs, etc like a new application. (For example armv7-neon optimized codecs for MX Player etc...)

I would love to know this because currently I am disabling neon to make android application compatible with more devices. If I can understand what's going on there, I can make a similar thing for myself, so owners of newer devices can install neon-optimized library?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Application.mk` file for your native code you can specify which ABIs you want to target. For example:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

Which says that you want to build the native code for both ARMv7, and the older ARMv6 (or maybe it was v5). Both versions of the library will be included with your app, and the most appropriate one will automatically be loaded at runtime.

In your `Android.mk` you could then put something like this:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_NEON=1
    LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
endif
```

And you could then place the NEON-specific code in your source files within `#ifdef HAVE_NEON ... #endif`. Another alternative would be to have all the NEON-specific code in its own source files, and only adding those files to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` when `ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)` is true.

Comment: Thanks. I actually need to put these ndk libs into store seperately and let user download them seperately according to their will. Then, the main application will load them accordingly. Seperate codec logic, as I have mentioned in my application. How do they do this?